# RDS firewall workaround for IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds

Looking at this post - it seems that Amazon has been working on providing a static IP for RDS - the comment was from about 18 months ago.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=596719

Is there any update on this - or a workaround using another service - last I checked Elastic IP was not doable either (based on a Sf question).

I have a similar issue as the poster of the other question - we have an internal app that accesses an RDS DB by hostname which is fine, however we have a mandated outbound firewall rule that needs to be set by the RDS instance's IP.

There was a patch and restart yesterday that broke that rule and it had to be reset, would love to avoid this in the future.

Thanks

Comment: Probably better to ask Amazon directly instead of here..

Comment: tried... my account can't post in the forums yet - will try again tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Today an EIP cannot be attached to a RDS instance.

Think about Multi-AZ instances, those are two instantes one working an one in stand-by. When The master fails AWS changes the DNS name to point to the stand-by

Perhaps you can use an Route53 alias record which works like a CNAME but resolves like an A record

Comment: +1 for route53 ALIAS.